# Change localization on becoming active

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I need to change localization of the iOS application when it becomes active.

So..

I have a language selector in Settings made through `settings.bundle` in the `main.m` file. I'm reading settings like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    // --
    NSString *appLang = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"appLang"];

    if (appLang == nil)
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"appLang"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
         setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"appLang"], nil]
         forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        [appLang release];
        // --
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
        [pool release];
        return retVal;
    }
```

So the application changes images for different languages using data from settings.

Right now, I'm using conditions to define the language like this one:

```
if ([[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:@"en"])
```

All works fine, but the question is: can I change localization of the application (using my method) when the application becomes active (applicationWillEnterForeground or something like this)? And how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` in your view controller. You can do this like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myFunc) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

When app will enter foreground `myFunc` will be called and there you will be able to setup everything - set proper localization, switch images etc.

---

I don't know if it's exactly what you need, but assuming that you have an UIImageVIew called `myImage` and you want to load a new image to this container, you just set it's image property you can set your `myFunc` like this:

```
- (void) myFunc {
    /* 
    set localization parameters
    */ 
    // set image
    myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img_%@.jpg", appLang]];
}
```

Comment: i know this. actually my question is "what have i to change". im changing AppleLanguages in UserDefaults but images still dont change.

Comment: no. its nor what i want = ) i have about 1500+ images in about 55 viewControllers. i think i need a way to reload app somehow to have all my resources localized automatically